# Exclude file/folder form a release merge using git-flow

Tags: git, workflow, git-flow

I was wondering if there is any way to exclude a file/folder from develop to master branch merge when I finish a release using git-flow?

Example: I have index.html and Gruntfile.js on develop branch and I only want the index.html to be merge on the master branch.

I'm asking this because I have a dev folder on my develop branch that include files which are not necessary for the master branch (like gruntfile.js, scss file, etc) so I would prefer not to include it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The thing you want to do doesn't look like a good idea in the first place. Can you explain why are you removing some files from your release branches? I feel you are doing it the wrong way

Comment: I want to do this because I need some files that are only related to development in my develop branch (gruntfile.js, scss files, etc) and I would like only the files I need to production in my master branch. But you probably right about the fact that it does not seem like a good idea because I can't find anybody with the same workflow :) So if you could suggest me a better one I would be pleased

Comment: `git` is supposed to be used to track _source code_, not production files. in `git flow` the `master` branch is supposed to be used to save snapshot of the develop files, in order to be able to regenerate a build, so it should have any file you need. In javascript _source code_ and _production files_ is almost the same, so it can get confusing, however if it is not exactly the same you probably want to write some kind of packaging script or similar: the script should copy only the required files into a suitable `build` directory, which you can then zip and send to a client/make it downloadable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to make some changes to code repository before declaring it as your new version you should use a *release branch*, i.e.:

```
git checkout -b release-1.4
git rm gruntfile.js # this could be an automated script
git commit -m "removed files before release"
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff release-1.4
```

see git flow article for further detail

http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Keep in mind however that maybe this is not what you really want (see comment to question). According to git flow paradigm edits made in a release branch should be merged not only into `master` but also back into `develop`. This ensures that next release branch will be a direct descendent of the previous release branch, thus will merge cleanly into `master`. In your case, you can't do this, because you would have these files disappear from `develop` too.

Comment: Nice, I did not think of this. But your right it won't work if I use the git-flow hotfix... I probably have to keep my dev files on the master branch...

Comment: it is usually a good idea to just keep everything in the release commit, but to create a release `.zip` with a script that does not copy the files to be ignored

Answer (score 0):

Sure! Just make a  `.gitignore`  file in the base of your local git repository and add all the files (relative to the  `.gitignore`  location that you would like git to ignore. To ignore a file called xxx.yyy in the aaa directory, you would add `aaa/xxx.yyy` to `.gitignore`.

This answer does not use git-flow, however git-flow does need to be used.

Further reading can be found [here.](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Comment: Problem is I want the file/folder to be tracked on the develop branch but not in the master branch. Example: develop branch contains index.html and Gruntfile.js => I want the master branch only containing the index.html file. So I need a way to only merge the index.html file but I'm not sure if there is a way to do this...

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for that scenario but it requires that you edit files in the .git/ directory: https://nbit001.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/git-ignore-files-for-certain-a-branc/ - don't feels like the best practice solution though. I think pqnet is right, the thing you are describing is more the job of a CI tool like Travis, TeamCity, Jenkins...